# ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation::InvalidType ("html" is not a valid MIME type):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, ruby-on-rails-7

I am upgrading my rails app from ruby 2.4 to ruby 3.2.2 and from rails 5 to rails 7.0.4.3. After upgrading a bunch of gems and getting the app up and running, I started getting the above error. The error occurs when I click a button that is meant to create an overlay where you can select a start and end date to filer a report. This is the back trace:

```
 - - [18/Mar/2024:11:18:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 103 0.0168
Started GET "/reports/report_params/jvcd_history" for XXXXXXX at 2024-03-18 11:18:53 -0400
  
ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation::InvalidType ("html" is not a valid MIME type):
```

I am using mimemagic. I am not using sentry-ruby.
I tried upgrading mimemagic to the latest version (0.4.3) but that hasn't worked.

I also checked my Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES and html is certainly there.

I tried creating an exception handler but that's not really the route I want to go because I think there is something else going on here.

I also tried adding a `defaults: { format: 'html' }` in `routes.rb` for the route but that didnt work either.

Comment: `html` isn't actually a valid mime type value but`text/html` is. If I had to guess whats going it's some wonky javascript thats sending a request with a  `ContentType=html` header.

Comment: Use the browsers network tab to look at the request sent by the browser. Pay special attention to the ContentType and Accept headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

Comment: I found a rogue js file that had contentType: "html" instead of "text/html" and it worked!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to find a .js file that had `contentType: "html"`  instead of `contentType: "text/html"`. Making that change fixed the error for me!